# Unicode error - POST request with file object

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, python-unicode

I have a file which is called `testing-unicode-ö.png`. I want to create a file object and send it in a payload to my `API` where the contents will be read and the file object name will be formatted.

This code fits into a [APITestCase](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#test-cases) subclass in my `django-rest-framework` tests.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

fname = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "./testing-unicode-ö.png"))
f = open(fname.encode('utf-8'))

payload = {"file": f}
headers = {"HTTP_X_SECRET_KEY": "some-key"}
url = "some-url"

response = self.client.post(url, data=payload, **headers)
```

I am getting a `UnicodeDecodeError` when trying to do the `self.client.post`:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/sapi/widgets/tests/test_api.py", line 1517, in test_image_upload_no_unicode_error
    response = self.client.post(url, data=payload, **headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 170, in post
    path, data=data, format=format, content_type=content_type, **extra)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 91, in post
    data, content_type = self._encode_data(data, format, content_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 66, in _encode_data
    ret = renderer.render(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 782, in render
    return encode_multipart(self.BOUNDARY, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/client.py", line 170, in encode_multipart
    lines.extend(encode_file(boundary, key, value))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/client.py", line 214, in encode_file
    % (key, filename)),
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It blows up in `client.py` in `django`-land. Stumped.

My setup is: 
`Ubuntu 15.04, python 2.7.3, django 1.8.2, django-rest-framework 3.2.2`

Comment: You're not passing the filename anywhere in the post, so it isn't because of that o-umlaut. Perhaps you just need to open the file in binary mode?

Comment: Well, the stack trace has a reference to `% (key, filename))`, so I think in the `POST` background, something is being done with the name. Trying a `open(fname.encode('utf-8'), 'rb')` still gives the same error.

Comment: What is your DEFAULT_CHARSET setting?

Comment: It is 'utf-8'. In any case, according to the docs, we can't rely on this for the long term: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/

Comment: How are you calling your test?

Comment: I use docker/docker-compose, so the command is something like `docker-compose run web python manage.py test appname.tests.test_api.test_unicode`